# WPF - Overlapping Custom Tabs in a TabControl and ZIndex

Tags: wpf, tabcontrol, z-index, tabitem

**Problem**
I have a custom tab control using Chrome-shaped tabs that binds to a ViewModel. Because of the shape, the edges overlap a bit. I have a function that sets the tabItem's ZIndex on `TabControl_SelectionChanged` which works fine for selecting tabs, and dragging/dropping tabs, however when I Add or Close a tab via a Relay Command I am getting unusual results. Does anyone have any ideas?

**Default view:**
[image]

**Removing Tabs:**
[image]

**Adding 2 or more Tabs in a row:**
[image]

Adding more then 1 tab at a time will not reset the zindex of other recently-added tabs so they go behind the tab on the Right, and closing tabs does not correctly render the ZIndex of the SelectedTab that replaces it and it shows up behind the tab on its right.

**Code to set ZIndex**

```
private void PrimaryTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source is TabControl)
        {
            TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;
            ItemContainerGenerator icg = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator;
            if (icg.Status == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
            {
                foreach (object o in tabControl.Items)
                {
                    UIElement tabItem = icg.ContainerFromItem(o) as UIElement;
                    Panel.SetZIndex(tabItem, (o == tabControl.SelectedItem ? 100 :
                        90 - tabControl.Items.IndexOf(o)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

By using breakpoints I can see that it is correctly setting the ZIndex to what I want it to, however the layout is not displaying the changes. I know some of the changes are in effect because if none of them were working then the tab edges would be reversed (the right tabs would be drawn on top of the left ones). Clicking a tab will correctly set the zindex of all tabs (including the one that should be drawn on top) and dragging/dropping them to rearrange them also renders correctly (which removes and reinserts the tab item). The only difference I can think of is I am using the MVVM design pattern and the buttons that Add/Close tabs are relay commands.

Does anyone have any idea why this is happening and how I can fix it??

p.s. I did try setting a ZIndex in my ViewModel and binding to it, however the same thing happens when adding/removing tabs via the relay command.

Comment: I'm now thinking it is an issue with WPF and not my code. I added a button which displays the zIndex of the tab items after they get drawn and the zIndex is definitely correct on all of them, they are just not getting drawn correctly.

Comment: Hi there. Giving tabs in a TabControl the Chrome-like trapezoidal shape and getting them to behave correctly does indeed seem to be quite tricky in WPF. Any chance you could share the XAML you used for the templating/styling? I have a solution here, but it's not particularly elegant - curious what you've done! Cheers.

Comment: Sure, the code is a little too long to post here but I'll try to explain it. If you have questions feel free to email me at rlim@email.itt-tech.edu. Each Tab is actually a Grid with 3 cells - Left and Right ones contain a Path that draws the curve and the middle one contains the data. Each Grid has a negative margin set to make them overlap, and the zIndex is used to set which one should be on top. Not sure if you're adding drag/drop or scrolling but in my case all the Tabs are contained in a ScrollViewer for scrolling and the DragDrop is an attached property for the TabControl's ItemsControl.

Comment: @Rachel, couldn't this be done by creating a Panel other than TabPanel that would re order it's children in reverse and in doing so giving them the wanted Z-Order ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Thank you Abe, your second comment lead me to my solution!

I added `tabItem.Dispatcher.Invoke(DispatcherPriority.Render, EmptyDelegate);` to each iteration of the loop.

I would still be interested in learning if anyone else finds a way around this without refreshing each tabItem on every change. I tried refreshing the entire tab control at the end of the loop but that only worked for closing tabs, not adding them. I know that Panel.ZIndex is getting set correctly, it's just not honoring that property when rendering.

EDIT: The above line of code was causing an unusual flicker when Dragging/Dropping the tabs that would briefly show the tab behind the one being dragged. I moved the code to a separate function and called it at a lower dispatcher priority and this fixed the problem. Final code is below:

```
private void PrimaryTabControl_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Source is TabControl)
        {
            TabControl tabControl = sender as TabControl;

            tabControl.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                new Action(() => UpdateZIndex(sender as TabControl)),
                DispatcherPriority.Background);
        }
    }

    private void UpdateZIndex(TabControl tabControl)
    {
        ItemContainerGenerator icg = tabControl.ItemContainerGenerator;

        if (icg.Status == System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.GeneratorStatus.ContainersGenerated)
        {
            foreach (object o in tabControl.Items)
            {
                UIElement tabItem = icg.ContainerFromItem(o) as UIElement;
                if (tabItem != null)
                {
                    // Set ZIndex
                    Panel.SetZIndex(tabItem, (o == tabControl.SelectedItem ? 100 :
                        90 - tabControl.Items.IndexOf(o)));
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Upgrading to .Net 4.0 also fixed the problem

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you just need to run your algorithm again when the collection changes.  Since you are testing the `ItemContainerGenerator.Status` property, the algorithm may not run.  You may want to consider listening to the `StatusChanged` event, and when it changes to `ContainersGenerated` run the algorithm again.

Comment: I have tried this and it still does not show up correctly. Also, the ItemContainerGenerator.StatusChanged event runs before the SelectedItem is updated so setting it always sets the selected tab to the last-selected tab. By using breakpoints I can see that the Panel.ZIndex is definitely getting set correctly when adding/removing tabs using the TabControl_SelectionChanged event, however it does not draw them the way it should. To me this doesn't make sense since Drag/Dropping tabs (which also removes and re-adds the tabItem) draws the tab order correctly.

Comment: Yeah, that is odd.  The only difference I can think of between d&d and just adding a new item would be the timing of when the z-index algorithm is run.  Perhaps invoking it on the Dispatcher at a lower priority (like DispatcherPriority.Input) would be a (hacky) solution.