# WPF: How to make a Google Chrome style GUI in WPF/MVVM?

Tags: wpf, user-interface, google-chrome, mvvm, drag-and-drop

I bet you guys know Google Chrome browser, yeah it comes from Chromium open-source projects, added some Google specific features.

I found the multi-tab GUI is quite attractive, especially the "drag-and-drop" feature for tabs and windows:

- to "pull a tab" out to form a separate window, or
- vice versa, to join a tab into a windows (that has a collection of tabs).

This would be quite helpful for designing some multi-process applications to achieve the stability, and a cool user experience, but ... how?

1. is it possible to do this in WPF?
2. or even one step more, is it possible to do this in MVVM?

Yeah, technically, everything is possible, but I can't see an easy pattern to do this

1. for WPF, how to handle such specific "crossing window" mouse interaction?
2. for MVVM, hmmm, will this be too challenging for MVVM?

cheers

Comment: No idea, but you might want to check out the RibbonWindow, which does with its chrome something similar...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Its definitely possible. I've recreated the chrome tab look in the past with MVVM, complete with drag and drop, and I know another guy who created a tabbed application that lets you "pull away" tabs into a new window of its own. I believe it was all one application with multiple windows, so all open windows were part of the same application even if they show up separately in the task bar.

I'm not sure if I have his source code or not, I'd have to go digging for it.

Comment: @athos I did, but it's pretty simple since it was just to test an idea. He has a custom `Window` class which accepts an object in the constructor, and when you Double-Click a tab in a TabControl it creates a new CustomWindow using the SelectedTab, then removes the SelectedTab from the list. It could be done better using a Drag/Drop framework to drag around tabs, a VisualBrush for the Adorner, and on MouseUp if the mouse isn't over the application (might need the MouseLeave event), create a new CustomWindow using the DraggedItem

Comment: Check out http://bea.stollnitz.com/blog/?p=53 for a good Drag/Drop example. I used a modification of her code to make a TabControl's items draggable

Comment: @Rachel Hi I'm very interested in looking at the project/code. Do you happen to remember the project name or another active link?

Comment: @Master I'm sorry, I don't have access to the code anymore. I should probably remove this answer and get it changed to a comment. I had some images and a short explanation on how to draw the tabs [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525030/wpf-overlapping-custom-tabs-in-a-tabcontrol-and-zindex#comment2749881_2525030), however I don't think I have any of the code for dragging/dropping tabs to new windows or back to an existing one.

Answer (score 2):

maybe you should have a look at these libs/frameworks:

http://fabtab.codeplex.com/

http://avalondock.codeplex.com/

http://fluidkit.codeplex.com/