# Incorrect appearance after property change at runtime in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I have this problem with a WPF application, when the properties of control changes they do not get refreshed visually! I am using snoop and I can see that the property is set correctly but it does not affect the control. I noticed that if I change the size it get refresh and it corrects the appearance of the control .

This application has multiple pages (controls which inherit page) and there is navigation bar to navigate to each of these pages. There is an option in the menu that let the user to change a visual property (“FlowDirection” of the controls) this calls a method which loads a resource dictionary which apply new styles for whole framework elements. I noticed that if the user change it (by using that menu item), all the controls in the page which is displaying are get refreshed and it works fine. But when we navigate to the other pages some control are refreshed and some of them not! (as I mentioned earlier I used snoop and it shows that the correct value is set for the property of the controls in all other pages, and if I resize the page they get in to the correct position)

I tried InvalidateVisual , InvalidateArrange , InvalidateMeasure, and none of them helped .

The code is in WPF C#, .NET 4.0

Any suggestion?

Comment: It would help if you posted some code showing how the control is written and bound, and how the ViewModel class is written.  It sounds like your VM class is not raising notifications correctly when the properties change, but without sample code it's impossible to say.

Comment: I had a [similar issue](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2548195/302677) where the property was updated, but the UI wasn't, and I ended up resolving it by running the code at a lower `DispatcherPriority` than Normal. Perhaps that might work for you?

Comment: Thanks for reply, 
the navigation is really complicated (it is based on a custom framework system and so many component involved) I tried to simulate the problem by creating a simple solution to mimic the behavior but since it is so complicate I found it almost impossible to do it in short time ( I mean it takes more than a week!).

Comment: I haven’t written the code but I can explain it, there is no manual binding involved in this case, there are 2  sets of style (as resource dictionaries) (which are setting FlowDirection Properties for FrameworkElement and some built in controls (like Grid, and text block)) according to the chosen option (from menu) one of these set will be loaded.  There is no view model here it is only a visual control which has no behavior, it just displays something

Comment: inside it.
As I mentioned snoop shows that the property is set correctly so after changing the option the property gets the correct value, it means that the resources are loaded correctly ( as I mentioned, there are some other controls in the same page which are working properly)

Comment: @Rachel, would you explain it a little bit more, I havn't try that. Which state did you choose?

Comment: @FredJand The link I provided in my comment above shows the code I used to fix the issue for my case. The default [DispatcherPriority](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcherpriority.aspx) for running code is `Dispatcher.Normal`, which runs before `DispatcherPriority.Render`, however in my case the UI was not updating correctly. Running the code at `DispatcherPriority.Background`, which runs after `DispatcherPriority.Render`, caused the UI to update correctly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Binding, you need to either use DependencyProperties, or make sure that you implement INotifyPropertyChanged in your code-behind, and whenever the properties change, you need to call OnPropertyChanged("PropertyName") where 'PropertyName' is the name of your property, and OnPropertyChanged is your implementation (shown below) for the INotifyPropertyChanged interface.

```
#region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

public void OnPropertyChanged(string prop)
{
    if (PropertyChanged != null)
    {
        PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(prop));
    }
}

#endregion
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, but this is not the case. Proprty is FlowDirection which is a UIFrameworkElement property (so it is a dp by nature) and nothing exlplicitly assign it, it gets set indirectly by loading a resource dictionary.